# Binding: 'XXX' property not found on 'YYY', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms using MVVM. I'm getting the following in the log:

Binding: 'XXX' property not found on 'YYY', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'

Not sure is it related but when I update a variable within my Command function, this variable's updated value is not being reflected in the view.
This is not happening in my other viewmodels and views. I'm not sure why.

Please help!

This is how I define the variable in the viewmodel and binding in the view.

ViewModel

```
public string _testContextPassing;
public string TestContextPassing
{
    get { return _testContextPassing; }
    set
    {
        testContextPassing = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }

//...

public override async Task Init()
{
    TestContextPassing = "123";
}

//...

TestContextPassing = "456";
```

View

```
<Label Grid.Row="2" BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference PhotoCapturePage}, Path=BindingContext}" Text="{Binding TestContextPassing}"/>
<Label Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding TestContextPassing}"/>
```

Comment: <Label Grid.Row="2" BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference PhotoCapturePage}, Path=BindingContext}" Text="{Binding TestContextPassing}"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding TestContextPassing}"/>

Comment: Don't you need to call OnPropertyChanged like this `OnPropertyChanged("TestContextPassing");`

Comment: In general: ICommand should be property, not a field. Common mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged to your class and do as below

```
 OnPropertyChanged("TestContextPassing");
```

or

```
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TestContextPassing));
```

Comment: Hi Ziyad, data is being passed successfully now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: please upvote my answer if you got a solution so other endeavors can also take benefit with this answer.