# Console.WriteLine returns correct value, however button gives error "Binding: 'Name' property not found on 'x.y.z Xamarin.Forms.Button.Text"

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

***Background info:***

I am working on an XAMARIN app, in which I try to generate dynamic buttons.

The `List` holds objects and these objects have properties. I try to single out an object from the `List` by using `foreach()`.

While looping I use `Console.WriteLine` before appending the property `Name` to my button. `Console.WriteLine` returns the correct values, but when I try to append this to my button, it returns the following error message:

```
Binding: 'Name' property not found on 'MobileApp.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Button.Text'
```

and in my application it shows the following text: `Xamarin.Forms.Button`

***What I have tried***

I looked up the error and have tried implementing the solutions (reference: [Binding: 'XXX' property not found on 'YYY', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45205652/binding-xxx-property-not-found-on-yyy-target-property-xamarin-forms-labe))

I have directly tried accessing the property from within the `foreach()` loop.

I have tried creating a property within the same class with the name `Name` and bind the property from within the `foreach` loop to the property and then use the property to bind it (to prevent the property name from not being "found).

I have tried using `{Binding Name}` after I tried the first method (the one described above)

I have tried creating a local variable and using that.

***The code***

```
    public static async void BuildDynamicButtons()
    {
        //wait until all data has been received
        IOTButtons = await App.IOTDatabase.GetItemsAsync();

        CompletedButtons.Clear();

        //instantiate buttion variable for the generated buttons
        Button button;

        //loop through all button properties and read it
        foreach (IOTButton buttonProperties in IOTButtons)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(buttonProperties.Name); //RESULTS IN THE CORRECT >STRING<
            //generate the button with the properties
            button = new Button
            {
                Text = buttonProperties.Name, //CANNOT FIND THIS
                CommandParameter = $"{buttonProperties.Topic}",
                HeightRequest = 75
            };
            //add the button to an ObservableCollection of buttons
            CompletedButtons.Add(button);
        }
    }
```

***The IOTButton class***

```
public class IOTButton
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Topic { get; set; }
}
```

***My XAML:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MobileApp.Views.DashboardPage"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MobileApp.ViewModels"
         Title="{Binding Title}"
         x:Name="Dashboard">

<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="Status" Priority="0" Order="Primary" Text="{Binding IsConnected}" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

<ContentPage.Content>
    <FlexLayout FlexLayout.Grow="1" Wrap="Wrap" JustifyContent="SpaceEvenly" x:Name="IOTButtonContainer" Margin="10">
        <Button
                Text="{Binding Name}"
                ContentLayout="Bottom,0"
                Image="coffee.png"
                Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.PublishCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=Dashboard}}" 
                CommandParameter="Test"
                HeightRequest="75">
        </Button>
        <Button
                Text="{Binding Name}"
                Command="{Binding ShowNewView}"
                ContentLayout="Bottom,0"
                Image="coffee.png"
                HeightRequest="75">
        </Button>
        <ListView x:Name="CompletedButtonsView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static vm:DashboardViewModel.CompletedButtons}}"></ListView>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding MQMessage}">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    Span="2"
                    VerticalItemSpacing="5" 
                    HorizontalItemSpacing="5"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </FlexLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

***Relevant XAML part:***

```
<ListView x:Name="CompletedButtonsView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static vm:DashboardViewModel.CompletedButtons}}"></ListView>
```

***Desired behavior:***

I would (ideally) want the property `Name` to be assigned from within the `foreach()` loop as follow: `buttonProperties.Name`.

Comment: @Cfun yes, all the other bindings work. The binding of CompletedButtons works as well, it's however that I cannot assign buttonProperties.Name to the text of the generated button you see in the code snippet

Comment: *...'Name' property not found on 'MobileApp.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel'....* Are you sure you are showing the correct code?

Comment: @Cfun IOTButtons is of type IOTButton

Comment: @SushiHangover yes. The method you see is IN DashboardViewModel. I see see it being bind correctly, it's just that the Text is not being assigned. That will return the X amount of buttons with the Text " Xamarin.Forms.Button.Text"

Comment: @Cfun I defined it myself.

Comment: do you mind share your IOTButton  although the error you get comes from xaml binding and not from the code you showed.

Comment: @Cfun made the edit

Comment: What about your xaml where you are binding?

Comment: @Cfun you want all of it or just a specific part?

Comment: @Cfun gave the complete XAML and narrowed it down to the relevant part as well.

Comment: I believe the problem is in your first two buttons `<Button Text="{Binding Name}"` it is expecting a property `Name` in your `BindingContext` but it didn't found it has nothing to do with your IOTButton. Try put a static text instad of the binding in your two buttons and see  `<Button Text="Whatever.." ../>`

Comment: @Cfun it still does not resolve the fact that my buttons return (I assume with the Text) " Xamarin.Forms.button", rather then the text I have provided in the generated part.

Comment: your ItemsSource, `CompletedButtons`, is a List of Buttons which are a UI object.  This is generally not how you provide data to a ListView.  Your ListView also doesn't have a DataTemplate, so it defautls to displaying the result of `ToString` which is the name of the class, `Xamarin.Forms.Button`

Answer (score 1):

your `ItemsSource`, `CompletedButtons`, is a List of `Buttons` which are a UI object. This is generally not how you provide data to a `ListView`. Your `ListView` also doesn't have a `DataTemplate`, so it defaults to displaying the result of `ToString` which is the name of the class, `Xamarin.Forms.Button`

if you want it to display the `Text` property, supply a template like this

```
<ListView x:Name="CompletedButtonsView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static vm:DashboardViewModel.CompletedButtons}}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextCell Text="{Binding Text}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

however, what I think you really want to do is this

```
// use IOTButtons as your source, CompletedButtons is not necessary
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding IOTButtons"}>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <Button Text="{Binding Name}" CommandParameter="{BindingTopic}" HeightRequest="75" />
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Would've been a great answer, had I not gotten the errors " The type ListView does not support direct content". Upon looking up the problem, I have come to conclusion I simply cannot install Microsoft.Xaml 4.0.0.1 due to it not being compatible with monoandroid90. I'll come back to you (later) to verify whether your answer is correct or not.

Comment: there were some syntax errors in my example that I just fixed